# Replacing second same character in line

Tags: notepad++

As you can probably see, I'm new here.
I've been searching for an answer to my question for an hour (yes, long time for this easy question) but I cannot find it.

The example of what I have (these are text files with few lines of text, but I've got a bunch of files):

```
G:072
O:2 
125/5 
K:201-5165/1988 
K:201-5165-1988
```

So what I would like it to look like:

```
G:072
O:2
125/5
K:201-5165/1988
K:201-5165/1988
```

I found a regex to find the second '-' in line but it doesn't work properly.

I use:`^(K[^-]*)-([^-]*)-(.*$)`
What I wanted it to do was to change - into /, but only the second -.
Instead of looking for only lines like `K:201-5165-1988`, it stops at first line with K, which already has the / `K:201-5165/1988`.

What do I do wrong? Why doesn't it look only for lines specified in regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+-.+\K-`
- Replace with: `/`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
  .+        : 1 or more any character
  -         : a dash
  .+        : : 1 or more any character
  \K        : forget all we have seen until this position
  -         : a dash
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this one is not important any more.
I will just post what I found so someone else with same problem could use it.

It is working with this regex: `^(.*)-(.*)-(.*$)`

and I replace it with `\1-\2/\3`